# Ansible AWX on K3s - Galaxy install problem "Failed to download collection tar from 'server0': <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known"

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx, ansible-tower

I have a problem with the Ansible AWX instance on K3s.

Used guide: https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-ansible-awx-on-ubuntu-linux/

I want to use the Ansible collections install option when syncing my project to git but that doesn't work.

I am using collections/requirements.yml file which during execution expects on a random collection (I want to install 7 collections from)

My collections:

- community.general
- community.mysql
- community.docker
- ansible.posix
- community.vmware
- community.zabbix
- awx.awx

Error with job details (Standard Error):

`ERROR! Failed to download collection tar from 'server0': <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>`

Error with manual installation in a container with -vvv and -c flags

```
bash-4.4$ ansible-galaxy collection install -r requirements.yml --collections-path /var/lib/awx/projects/.__awx_cache/_15__gitlab_ansible_awx_devops/stage/requirements_collections -vvv -c

ansible-galaxy [core 2.12.5.post0]
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/home/runner/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/runner/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible-galaxy
  python version = 3.8.12 (default, Sep 21 2021, 00:10:52) [GCC 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-3)]
  jinja version = 2.10.3
  libyaml = True
No config file found; using defaults
Reading requirement file at '/var/lib/awx/projects/_15__gitlab_ansible_awx_devops/collections/requirements.yml'
Starting galaxy collection install process
Process install dependency map
Opened /home/runner/.ansible/galaxy_token
[WARNING]: Skipping Galaxy server https://galaxy.ansible.com/api/. Got an unexpected error when getting available versions of collection community.general: Unknown
error when attempting to call Galaxy at 'https://galaxy.ansible.com/api/v2/collections/community/general/': <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
ERROR! Unknown error when attempting to call Galaxy at 'https://galaxy.ansible.com/api/v2/collections/community/general/': <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
```

It alternates between getting the error with "Network is unreachable" and "Name or service not known". Local installation goes without any problem.

Thanks for any help

Info:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- ansible [core 2.12.5.post0]
- AWX 21.1.0
- k3s version v1.23.6+k3s1 (418c3fa8)

Answer (score 0):

I hit a problem similar to yours and I think I'm halfway a solution. In order to debug your problem, I may suggest you to start by setting-up an ansible `~/.ansible.cfg` config file, since I see in your command output you're not using one. Add something like this:

```
[galaxy]
ignore_certs=False
server=https://galaxy.ansible.com/
```

Cheers